# como pegar o valor de uma checkbox expecifica no asp.net mvc usando JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Eu tenho uma tabela em um sistema em ASP.NET MVC que cada registro possui uma checkbox, eis o código abaixo da view:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="tabelaProdutos">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Tipo de Produto</th>
        <th>Cód. Categoria</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Ativado</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model.ListaProdutos)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Tipo</td>
            <td align="right">@item.Categoria</td>
            <td>@item.Descricao</td>
            <td align="justify" onclick="AtivarProduto(@item.ID)">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.Ativo)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Como posso pegar o valor da checkbox do item que acabei de clicar para ser usado para outros propósitos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode adicionar uma classe ao seu `CheckBox`, então usar ela como seletor.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.Ativo, new { @class = "ckAtivo" })
```

e no jQuery fazer o seguinte.:

```
$("#tabelaTiposCartao").on("click", ".ckAtivo", function () {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

o `this.value` vai ser o valor do checkbox. mas acredito que estaá abordagem faz o que você quer, porém não vai resolver o seu problema.

**SUGESTÕES**

Primeiro ponto seria quanto ao uso do `foreach` para montar a sua tabela, ao faze-lo, o `Razor` se perde na hora de atribuir um id e um `name` aos `inpus`,, então possivelmente você não vai receber os dados quando enviar eles de volta ao servidor.

então você tem duas opções, usar um `for` ou o nuget [`BeginCollectionItem`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/)

usando um `for`:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.ListaProdutos.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.ListaProdutos[i].Tipo</td>
        <td align="right">@Model.ListaProdutos[i].Categoria</td>
        <td>@Model.ListaProdutos[i].Descricao</td>
        <td align="justify" onclick="AtivarProduto(@item.ID)">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.ListaProdutos[i].Ativo)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

mas para usar esta abordagem, o seu `ListaProdutos` precisa ser um Tipo concreto como um `Array<T>` ou uma `List<T>` e não uma interface como o `IEnumerable<T>`, se este for o seu caso, a sua única opção será o pacote do nuget acima citado.

usando o [`BeginCollectionItem`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/):

```
using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("ListaProdutos"))
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Tipo)</td>
        <td align="right">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Categoria)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Descricao)</td>
        <td align="justify" onclick="AtivarProduto(@model.ID)">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Ativo)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Agora por valor do `CheckBox`, ele vai ter o valor da propriedade `Ativo`, ou seja `true` ou `false`, mas se você estiver interessado no `ID`, você terá de armazena-lo em algum lugar, como por exemplo em um `Hidden`.

E eu aplicaria uma classe na linha, para que eu pudesse pegar ela no javaScript e usar a linha como escopo para as minhas funções futuras.

```
using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("ListaProdutos"))
{
    <tr class="trProduto">
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Tipo)</td>
        <td align="right">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Categoria)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Descricao)</td>
        <td align="justify">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Ativo)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

agora segue o script:

```
var Produto = new Produto(container) {
    var that = this;
    this.dom = {};
    this.dom.linha = container;
    this.dom.celulas = this.dom.linha.querySelectorAll("td");
    this.dom.id = this.dom.linha.querySelector("[id$=ID]");
    this.dom.ativo = this.dom.linha.querySelector("[id$=Ativo]");

    this.dom.ativo.addEventListener("click", function () {
        that.onAtivoClick();
    });

    this.dom.celulas[3].addEventListener("click", function () {
        that.onCelula4Click();
    });
}

Produto.prototype.onAtivoClick = function () {
    console.log(this.dom.id.value); 
}

Produto.prototype.onCelula4Click = function () {
    AtivarProduto(this.dom.id.value);
}

var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".trProduto");
[].forEach.call(produtos, function (container, indice) {
    var produto = new Produto(container);   
});
```

no script acima, ele seleciona todas as linhas com a classe `.trProduto` então para cada linha ele procura os inputs cujo `id` termina com `ID` e`Ativo`.

Porém tomei a liberdade de criar uma "Classe" para ajudar a delimitar um escopo para cada linha, aqui chamado de produto.

se precisar ter acesso a outros dados, tais como o `Tipo`, `Categoria` ou `Descricao`, então crie um `HiddenFor` para eles também e faça a busca por eles dentro do objeto `Produto`, uma alternativa é pegar a propriedade `textContent` de `this.dom.celulas[i]`, onde `i` será `0`, `1` ou `2`.

Comment: interessante, mas como pego o valor da checkbox?:

Comment: @GustavoCorreiaSantos fiz uma longa edição na resposta, porém fui muito além do escopo da sua duvida, caso tenha alguma duvida sobre algumas das sugestões, por favor abra uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Uma pegunta: Este BeginCollectionItem substitui o for? ou precisa fazer o laço?

Comment: Sim, ele substitui.